# What is the rank of the set of functions from $\omega$ to $\omega$?

Tags: set-theory, infinity, ordinals

My stab was to say each member is a set of pairwise distinct ordered pairs of $\omega$ into $\omega$, so each function has rank $\omega + 1$ , therefore the entire set of functions has rank $\omega+ 2$

Does this work?

Comment: Why does each function have rank $\omega+1$?  What element of rank $\omega$ does such a function have?

Comment: Ah right sorry, I’m off by 1 then right? $\omega$ is the limit ordinal of the elements of each function so then the overall set would be $\omega+1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right idea but slightly off.  Each ordered pair of elements of $\omega$ has finite rank, so each function has rank $\omega$, not $\omega+1$ (it has no elements of rank $\omega$).  So, the set of all such functions has rank $\omega+1$.

Comment: Thanks! Makes total sense - as a generalisation then, if we have the set of functions from one limit ordinal A to another limit ordinal B, would its rank just be the successor of max(A,B) by the same logic?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

HINT. $rank(S)=\sup \{rank(T)+1:T\in S\}.$